# How to automatically hide and unhide rows in excel based on multiple cell value

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvFR9.png)I'm a newbie to excel macro.
I'm trying to create a macro to automatically hide and unhide rows in excel based on multiple cell value.
I have created two drop down cells with value using data validation and based on the drop down I'm trying to hide and unhide.
If the first drop down is "Class I" and second drop down value is Ä
only row from 8 to 20 should be visible and row from 21 to end of the rows to be hidden and similarly when the first drop down is "Class I" and second drop down value is "B" row from 8 to end of rows should be hidden except for rows from 23 to 31. If require I can provide the excel file it contains dummy data

Comment: What cells contain the two dropdows?

Comment: please provide some more info with specific details, you might add some screenshots

Comment: D3 and D4 cells contain the two drop down. I already have macro to clear cell D4 when value in D3 changes. Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
            On Error Resume Next
            If Target.Address = Range("D3").Address Then
            If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("D4").ClearContents
        End If
    End If

exitHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in the worksheet's private code sheet accessed though right-click worksheet name tab, View Code. Modify the row ranges to suit.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3, D4")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Range("8:" & Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Select Case Range("D3").Value2
            Case "Class I"
                Select Case Range("D4").Value2
                    Case ChrW(196)  'Ä
                        Intersect(Range("8:20"), Me.UsedRange).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Case "B"
                        Intersect(Range("21:33"), Me.UsedRange).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Case Else
                        'do nothing
                End Select
            Case "Class II"
                'copy above for Class I here
                'modify rows to show/hide
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    End If

meh:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. After copying the above for Class II and modify row to show/hide the macro stops working with following error Compile error
End if without block if